# Angular 2 new Router: How to get router parameters of a child component?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-routing

In the latest version of `@angular/router` `3.0.0-rc.1` The way you get the parameters from a URL/route changed.

Based on [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#query-parameters) documentation you should be able to get the params by subscribing to the params but in my case it seems that is not working.

What I want to achieve is to get params into my parent component FROM child routes.

For example let's say this is my routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'parent',
    component: ParentComponent,
    pathMatch: 'prefix',
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: ChildComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I want to get the `id` parameter and use it in my ParentComponent.
So I'm trying like this:

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  sub: any;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route = route;
   }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
     let id = params['id'];
     console.log(id);
   });

  }

}
```

Like this I'm getting:

> Undefined

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The `ActivatedRoute` has getters to access its parent/child route information.

In order to access the first child route from the parent, you would use:

`this.route.firstChild.params`

If you wanted all the child routes you would use the `children` property. This returns an array of `ActivatedRoute`

`this.route.children`

If you were in a child route and needed parameters from the parent:

`this.route.parent.params`

Comment: Thank you @Brandon!

Answer (score 18):

It's super easy to get the child parameters via ActivatedRoute, however you can quickly run into issues if you change the current child.

First a couple notes:

- `activatedRoute.firstChild` property is an `ActivatedRoute` instance and NOT an observable.
- Also note that `activatedRoute.paramMap` is an observable.

Here's how you can run into problems:

- Consider a component with two child routes - and corresponding components - where only one is shown at a time (for example a tabbed interface).
- If you access `firstChild.paramMap` inside your `ngOnInit` handler you'll be able to subscribe to it and monitor the parameters as they change. This will look and work just fine.
- If you switch to the second tab and then back to the first everything will break. This is because you originally subscribed `paramMap` on an ActivatedRoute instance that doesn't exist anymore.
- Important: This is only a problem if you're trying to access the child's `paramMap`. If you're trying to access your 'own' paramMap, or the child component also injects `paramMap` then everything will be fine.

The cleanest solution to this I've found is as follows:

Note: First inject `router: Router` in addition to `route: ActivatedRoute`.

```
const firstChildParams$ = this.router.events.pipe(filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
                                                  startWith(undefined),
                                                  switchMap(e => this.route.firstChild!.paramMap));
```

What this does is listens for only NavigationEnd events, after which a new `firstChild` will be available. By using `switchMap` you don't need to worry about unsubscribing to old redundant maps. Also not that the actual value of the navigation event is never used, and `startWith` is needed to be able to immediately handle parameters the first time.

I've been collecting helpful things like this into a RouterHelperService that I can inject anywhere, and not have to remember all this craziness.

---

Some day I may suggest that there should be an observable equivalent of `firstChild`, then this wouldn't be a problem. However it would perhaps introduce even more confusion in other scenarios!

Comment: thanks for your answer! this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Great :) hope I got all the details right. These things get tricky! I’d definitely also recommend making a service that takes ActivatedRoute as a dependency and exposes things like this. Then you can use it everywhere and if you ever find you did something wrong you only need fix it in one place.

Comment: This is a great answer. I wonder if there exists a better or different solutions now in year 2023. Also, why do you think having `firstChild` be an observable would cause even more confusion? I think `firstChild` should be an observable!

Comment: Thanks @Nick - I really wish there were some utility methods for this. Because frankly when I look at all the little helpers like this I've accumulated over the years it's kind of a mess. There may be some recent / future changes with the router reducing dependency on RxJs but I haven't really been following it.

Comment: I looked into it, and I'm pretty sure nothing exists yet. I created an issue on their github page: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/52894

Answer (score 5):

The child parameters are associated/stored with the child [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html).  They are not available on the parent's ActivatedRoute.  So you first need to get the child's ActivatedRoute using getter `firstChild` or `children`.

Then, the parent can either subscribe to child parameter changes:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute }               from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription }                 from 'rxjs/Subscription';

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   private sub: Subscription;
   constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
   ngOnInit() {
      this.sub = this.route.firstChild.params.subscribe(
        params => console.log(params.id));
   }
   ngOnDestroy() {
      this.sub.unsubscribe();
   }
}
```

or it can get a snapshot of the child parameters:

```
import { Component }      from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class ParentComponent {
   constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
   someMethod() {
      console.log(this.route.firstChild.snapshot.params.id);
   }
}
```

If you want to get all of the children (e.g., if you have multiple outlets),  use `ActivatedRoute.children` or `ActivatedRouteSnapshot.children` to get an array of child ActivatedRoutes or child ActivatedRouteShapshots.

Comment: Hey @Mark , thanks for informative answer, but do we always need to unsubscribe parameters subscription?

Answer (score 1):

By using `this.activatedRoute.snapshot.firstChild.params`

Answer (score 1):

```
  this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
            if (event instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
                // let strId = event.state.root.firstChild.children[0].data;
                let a = event.state.root.firstChild.children.map((route) => {
                    while (route.firstChild) {
                        route = route.firstChild;
                    }

                    return route;
                });
                console.log('Title', a[0].data.title);
                this.meta.updateTitle(a[0].data.title);
            }
            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                (<any>window).gtag('config', this.googleAnalyticsCode, {
                    'page_title' : this.titleService.getTitle(),
                    'page_path': event.urlAfterRedirects
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

Comment: when children's path has params this not working.