# Angular 2 router paths

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

i have 2 questions regarding Angular 2 router paths, i've spent some time googling about it, but with no luck, anyways i have following routes setup:

```
{ path: 'contract', component: ContractInsertUpdateComponent, children: [
         { path: '' },
         { path: ':id', component: ContractInsertUpdateComponent, children:[
                  { path: 'buyers', component : ContractTabBuyerComponent },
                  { path: 'seller', component : ContractTabSellerComponent }
        ]}                
]}
```

First of all, let me explain what i'm trying to achieve here, i want to use same component for both insert/update of contract. I also have more children routes and complete url should look something like

> localhost:4200/contract/2/buyers

1. First thing i'm curious of is default route of contract

   { path: '' }

If i understand it right if route is something like

> localhost:4200/contract

it should load ContractInsertUpdateComponent, which it does atm, my question is: Is this the right way to do it? Also I would like to avoid usage of empty component as default route if possible.

2. Rest of this route setup doesn't currently work, for example if i type something like

> localhost:4200/contract/2

im getting Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'contract/2'

In my understanding it should load ContractInsertUpdateComonent am i wrong?

I don't know where else to look for help, and I need some one to point me to the right direction...Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/contract/2 matches this route

```
{ path: '' },
```

because `/contract/2` starts with `''` (actually every route does)
and then searches for child routes of this route but fails because there are none.

```
{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

should fix it, because then the router doesn't search for routes that start with `''` but only for routes that **are** `''`

**update**

```
{ path: 'contract', component: ContractInsertUpdateComponent, children: [ 
    { path: '', pathMatch:'full', /* I guess you want some `component: ...` or `redirectTo: ...` here }, 
    { path: ':id', children:[ 
        { path: '', pathMatch:'full' }, 
        { path: 'seller', component : ContractTabSellerComponent } 
    ]} 
 ]}
```

Comment: Well, thanks, using your logic i managed to make it work (kind of) - i added `{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full' }`  on both children routes, so it looks like this now :

`{ path: 'contract', component: ContractInsertUpdateComponent, children: [
         { path: '', pathMatch:'full' },
         { path: ':id', children:[
                  { path: '', pathMatch:'full' },
                  { path: 'seller', component : ContractTabSellerComponent }
        ]}                
]}`
Now i have a problem because inside my ContractInsertUpdateComponent param (id) value is NaN. Any idea?

Comment: The `id` is only passed to `ContractTabSellerComponent`. Either you can use it there or pass it to the parent. There is also a way to find the child route with the parameter from the parent but that seems a bit fragile.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956129/angular-2-new-router-how-to-get-router-parameters-of-a-child-component for the later approach

Comment: Hmm yeah, i think your right...It does seem a little bit weird... I guess i'll have to reconfigure it...Thing is that i didn't want to load component or redirect on empty path, i just wanted to load InsertUpdateComponent on both routes - contract or contract/2 should both load same component (InsertUpdateComponent ) and edit route (contract/2) should have child routes - buyer and seller...anyway, tyvm for your help mate, i really appreciate it.