# Advanced angular routing - can this be done?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I need a help with advanced routing, cannot find any info how to achieve this.

I've got a app which I want it to me separated by sport type and city. Rest of the functionality should be the same. I don't want to repeat children, for all types and sports.

some routing examples:

```
/football/london/user/testUser/details
/cricket/manchester/user/testUser/achievements
/badminton/newyork/league/2018/spring/table
/tennis/sydney/league/2018/summer/fixtures
```

Is this possible to achieve without repeating children for type and cities?

Could anyone point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is quite easy to find if you study through the [Angular Router tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters). Basically you will want a `path: ':sport/:city'` with sub-nodes for `user`, `league`, etc.

Comment: so are you saying routing for user like this would work: path: ':sport/:city/user/:userName'?

Comment: yes, but ideally to avoid repetition you would do something like `{ path: ':sport/:city', children: [{ path: 'user/:userName', component: ...}, ...]}`, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40850695/angular-2-router-paths

Comment: ok yes it does, I've just checked, I didnt expect this would be that easy, thanks very much for your help, if you add this as answers I will mark it for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [Angular Router tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters), you can nest routes and use route parameters to capture variables in the URL. The route should look something like:

```
{path: ":sport/:city", children: [
    {path: "user/:userName", component: UserComponent},
    {path: "league/:year", component: LeagueComponent},
    ...
  ]}
```

Then `football/london/user/bob` routes to `UserComponent` with `sport => football, city => london, userName => bob`.

Comment: Generate your pages with `ng g module city --module sport --route :city`. This gives you a seperate module per page, where you load only the modules absolutely needed on this page. (For example: you don't need to import the `FormsModule` if you're only showing stuff)