# Route Resolve Root Component Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 6 application and I need some API call data in my root component.

I am trying to use RouteResolvers and I am not able to get it working.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'landingPage', pathMatch: 'full', resolve: {items: AuthRouteResolver}},
  {path: 'landingPage', component: LandingComponent, resolve: {items: AuthRouteResolver}},
  {path: 'modeler', component: ModelerComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
];
```

AuthRouteResolver.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Resolve} from '@angular/router';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

import {AuthService} from '../services/authService.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthRouteResolver implements Resolve<Observable<any>> {

  constructor(
    private _auth: AuthService
  ) {
  }

  resolve() {
    return this._auth.getAuthCorpID();
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <div id="footer">
      <div id="homepage">
        <button mat-button color="primary">
          <a (click)="clickedUrl()">Homepage</a>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div id="login-info">
        <span>Logged in as: </span>
        <span class="name">{{firstname}}</span>
        <span class="corpId">{{corpid}}</span>
      </div>

      <div id="feedback">
        <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="openDialog()">
          <span class="ng-scope">Feedback</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want the data from the AuthRouteResolver to be in this component.

I can get the data in the landingComponent but not here. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

The data resolved by a resolver resides in the active route.

Inject **private route:ActiveRoute** in your component constructor and look for

**this.route.snapshot.data['items']**;

Sometimes (depends on how you structure your router) you have to look in the parent route

**this.route.parent.snapshot.data['items']**;

I would do a console.log and try to find the right location

Comment: OP asked about using data resolved for children in parent

Comment: I did this. this.route.snapshot.data['items'] returns undefined and the second one says its not able to find snapshot

Comment: this.route.snapshot.data is an empty object. Is it because I am redirecting to landingComponent when route is '' ?

Comment: Thanks for the -1. The answer is still valid, the data has to be contained in Activeroute. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956129/angular-2-new-router-how-to-get-router-parameters-of-a-child-component